# how to get the the out parameter of the stored procedure using the mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

My stored procedure has a out parameter called '@var', which will be an integer value. 
I m able to execut the stored procedure but later I m not able to get the value of out parameter.

This proble has arrised when I changed from mysql to mysqli.

When I was using mysql connection the code was working fine, the code was as shown below

```
    $query = "CALL myStoredProcedure('$LocationIdToEdit',@var)";           
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT @var;");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $myVar = $row[0];
```

Now I changed mysql to mysqli, as shown below

```
    $query = "CALL myStoredProcedure('$LocationIdToEdit',@var)";           
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT @var;");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
    $myVar = $row[0];
```

now the $row value is null, but if I execute the same code in the query browser, its working fine but inside php its not.....

```
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT @var;");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
```

this is retuning the null value.

Please, could anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(  "HOST", "USR", "PWD", "DBNAME" );
$LocationIdToEdit= //your value here
$res = $mysqli->multi_query( "CALL myStoredProcedure($LocationIdToEdit,@var)" );
 do {
if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
  printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );
  while( $row = $result->fetch_row() ) {
    foreach( $row as $cell ) echo $cell, "&nbsp;";
  }
  $result->close();
  if( $mysqli->more_results() ) echo "<br/>";
}
} while( $mysqli->next_result() );
```

Comment: dipous, I need value of @var variable

Comment: Getting an ERROR as "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int"

Comment: I removed the line "printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );" so its working fine..
................ Thanks a lot idipous